# Z3 is not able to detect contradictory statement with existential quantifier

Tags: z3, z3py

I have constructed a contradictory z3 program. I have added a few constraints, then add the contradictory statement with the existential quantifier(`Exists([_x1,_y1,_z1],Implies(And(_CV1+_CE1<=_z1,And(_CE1<=_x1,_x1<_y1)),And(ForAll([_n1],Implies(And(_n1>=_x1,_n1<_y1),_z1+_f(_n1)<a)),_z1+_y1>=a)))`)

```
a=Int('a')
c=Int('c')
b=Int('b')
_n=Int('_n')
_CV1=Int('_CV1')
_CS1=Int('_CS1')
_CE1=Int('_CE1')
_x1=Int('_x1')
_y1=Int('_y1')
_z1=Int('_z1')
_n1=Int('_n1')
_f=Function('_f',IntSort(),IntSort())
_s=Solver()
_s.set("timeout",50000)
_s.add(ForAll([_n],Implies(_n>=0, _f(_n)==_n)))
_s.add(_CS1>=0)
_s.add(_CE1>_CS1)
_s.add(ForAll([_n1],Implies(And(_n1>=_CS1,_n1<_CE1),_CV1+_f(_n1)<a)))
_s.add(_CV1+_CE1>=a)  
_s.add(Exists([_x1,_y1,_z1],Implies(And(_CV1+_CE1<=_z1,And(_CE1<=_x1,_x1<_y1)),And(ForAll([_n1],Implies(And(_n1>=_x1,_n1<_y1),_z1+_f(_n1)<a)),_z1+_y1>=a))))
```

z3 return the following counterexample

```
[_y1!1 = 1,_x1!2 = 5,a = 1,_CS1 = 0,_CE1 = 1,_CV1 = 0,_z1!0 = 0,_f = [0 -> 0, else -> Var(0)]]
```

There is constraint `_x1<_y1` in the implication of the statement with the existential quantifier. Strangely  counterexample `_y1!1 = 1,_x1!2 = 5`. I am not able to understand why it returns these values.

If I remove existential quantifier, constructed following query it results in the contradiction.

```
_s.add(_CS1>=0)
_s.add(_CE1>_CS1)
_s.add(ForAll([_n1],Implies(And(_n1>=_CS1,_n1<_CE1),_CV1+_f(_n1)<a)))
_s.add(_CV1+_CE1>=a)  
_s.add(_x1>=_CE1)
_s.add(_y1>_x1)
_s.add(_CV1+_CE1<=_z1)
_s.add(ForAll([_n1],Implies(And(_n1>=_x1,_n1<_y1),_z1+_f(_n1)<a)))
_s.add(_z1+_y1>=a)
```

Can you please help me understand why the first z3 program return not returning the desired result. Please point out if I am making any mistake?

Comment: Please post a description of what problem you are trying to solve; and a minimal example that we can load to z3py to experiment. Without any context, it's impossible to tell what (if anything!) you might be doing wrong.